# Translating HTML/JS/CSS to Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

At the moment I have created a webpage that makes use of HTML, CSS, and Javascript but I need to implement ruby on rails next in order to do back end stuff as well as it's what my boss told me to utilize. Now I have never utilized Ruby on Rails so any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

Now I know that CSS has pre-processors such as SASS and others but how exactly do I utilize these. I also understand the basic structure of Rails in that there are different controllers and each one corresponds to different things.

Basically I would just like some guidance on how to implement a Ruby on Rails framework.

If you need any other information, I would be glad to oblige you with it.

Comment: You're asking how to write an application in Rails? I suggest you start with the official guides: [Getting Started](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html]).

Comment: Google "Getting started with Ruby on Rails." Also, do yourself and your boss a favor and tell him you're an absolute noob when it comes to Rails

Comment: http://rubyonrails.org/ ...the fact that you didn't start in the most obvious place is a bad sign of things to come.

Comment: @AndréDion I'm sorry I didn't say that I started there but I did read about what ruby on rails is. It's extremely rude to also attack my skills as well for asking a question, albeit maybe not the best question in the world but being so condescending is never a good sign for people answering a question.

Comment: @terrabl Let's try and stay civil here. The reason you're getting a lot of flack is because this question doesn't show a whole lot of research on your part. Stack Overflow is not the place for general discussion, there are forums aplenty for that, but one where you can have a *specific* technical problem resolved. If you need training, a course, or a reference, that's fine, but this is not the place to ask for that sort of advice.

Comment: Nobody has answered your question because it's complete trash and shows a total lack of research. Nobody here has assaulted your supposed "skills" either; you are new to RoR and seemingly software development in general. Learning how to ask good questions is a part of becoming a good developer and so is taking constructive criticism.

Comment: @AndréDion I understand where I went wrong and I'm sorry. I realize that I am not the best developer and I let my ego get the best of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so there's nothing bad at being a beginner level of a developer on anything. The fact that you want to learn and get better at it is more important. So, you'd want to the following things:

1. First of all, you need to set your environment. This would depend on your machine configurations. Once you have your environment ready, you can proceed further.
2. Get to know Rails better. Get adept at using Ruby on Rails.This is going to be your primary back-end stuff. You can start reading about it here: http://rubyonrails.org/, here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html and here: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/
3. Figure what database you'd like to pair it up with. Practice a little with the db queries and see you're able to filter whatever data you want to. Most often, MySql, SQLite and PostgreSql work best with RoR. But then again, One of the tenets of Rails is you shouldn't really care what database you're using: that's all abstracted for you.
4. Integrate RoR with your front-end (Javascript). This is usually pretty straight-forward. You can use rails on your front-end too (for eg., you can use rails forms instead of pure html forms). You can read more about it here: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html
5. Add CSS styles to your html.erb files. This works like any other .html files. You may or may not use SASS. Ruby on Rails works fine even with pure CSS. You can also have CSS libraries like Bootstrap. (Isn't that cool! :P). You can learn more about integrating Saas with RoR here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dKe2sP-NAxQ
6. Another important note to keep in mind would be to write RSpec tests at each step to confirm that your code is working fine and is not effecting any other section of code. You can read more about it here: http://rspec.info/ and http://betterspecs.org/.

And that's it, you are good to go! :)